# Image behind another. HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am new to website designing, and I need help with something easy.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsyIi.jpg

How can I make the 5 buttons display on top of the little banner?

I added,

```
position: relative; 
     top: -8px;
```

and that worked but I want the banner to be behind the navigation buttons.

Answer (score 2):

use z-index in their style.

higher z-index will be placed on top.

Answer (score 0):

Use `z-index` in your CSS to move the buttons to the foreground.

[z-index on CSS-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)

Comment: I did it now, but the banner goes all the way on top. Trying to fix it at the most, but i have been working on my website for 7 hours now, so don't want to spent more time. EDIT: FIXED.

Comment: Ah, I've been working on my website for 10 years, and it's still not finished. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
display:inline-block 
//or 
display:inline-block;
//or use float-left
float:left;//for all buttons 
z-index:1; //default value is 0 or auto
```